# Call routing via android application

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application where i can route my calls via land line network. It should allow me to answer land line phone call and allow me to make calls from my App which will route through your configured land line phone network.

I do not expect any code help just conceptual understanding how this could be achieved ?

Comment: please post your research and code here.

Comment: Your question is (1) too broad (2) primarily opinion based (3) is not about programming ... all reasons to close this question.

Comment: @Dato'Mohammad Nurdin Sir, i haven't kick started it and awaiting for concrete replies on possibilities for it.
With respect to research, As we know calling is integral part of Android OS features but i want to enhance it or rather develop it to a level in which we could remove dependency of telecom service provider and route incoming/outgoing calls via configured land line number.

Comment: Please find this link:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48356/use-my-land-line-with-android
This could answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very complicated thing, And it really needs lot of free time and immense amount of understanding level. [Asterisk](http://www.asterisk.org/get-started) could be your starting point here.

Please look at :

[Android (SIP app)] --Ethernet/WLAN--> [VOIP Gateway]

[Home Phone] --Analog Line --> [VOIP Gateway]

[VOIP Gateway] --Analog Line--> [PSTN (your phone company)]

Also try to have a good look @ [SIPDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sipdroid.sipua&hl=en) Application.